# Can this javascript code (or part of it) be moved to a separate file instead of inlined?

Tags: javascript, html

I have been battling this 3rd party code when it comes to page speed, as it stops the page from rendering until it loads. I accept it will take a moment for it to populate, but I'm trying to prevent the whole page from stalling.

This is what is inlined in the HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var CompanyExchange = {
    "type": "ad_unit",
    "placement_id": "--RANDOMNUMBER",
    "version": "17",
    "sub_1": "KEYWORD",
    "data": { 
        "zip": "auto"
    }
};
</script>
<script src="//domainname.com/js/serve.js"></script>
```

Can I move the top part to a separate file, add it to a minified js file, and place it in the footer? I'm wondering if it won't fire because the script src will be called inline before the script type loads.

Any other ways to make this more efficient?

Answer (score 2):

It's not the block at the top that's causing the delay, it's the other one. The block at the top will run in microseconds at most.

In most cases, you could move both of them to the bottom of the page (just before the closing `</body>` tag), which would be [best practices](https://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom).

**However**, that looks like an ad block, which means ([as Niet the Dark Absol points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36954088/can-this-javascript-code-or-part-of-it-be-moved-to-a-separate-file-instead-of/36954205?noredirect=1#comment61466239_36954205)) it probably injects HTML into your page at the location where the script is placed (e.g., using `document.write` and similar), in which case moving it will (obviously) move the HTML it injects — in your case, the ad.

Some ad networks provide a means of "deferred loading" (Google does, for instance). Whether yours does is something you'll have to take up with them.

Comment: Yes, it is an ad block. It sounds like I may need to speak with the ad network to determine if there is a better way to implement this.